# Toggle Months / Years

Tags: jquery

Just doing a snippet for toggling months/years. I have achieved half of it, but in that half there is a glitch if you hit previous arrow. There is a blank space after January.

You can see my code here:

jQuery:

```
    var $months = [
    "",
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"];

var d = new Date();
var $m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var $y = d.getFullYear();

$('.history-months').click(function () {
    var num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var future_month = parseFloat(num) - 1;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
    if (num < 2) {
        $('.months').attr("month-count", 13);
    }
});
$('.future-months').click(function () {
    var num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var future_month = parseFloat(num) + 1;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
    if (num > 10) {
        $('.months').attr("month-count", 0);
    }
});

$('.months').text($months[$m]).attr('month-count', $m);
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="history-months">&LT;</a>

<span class="months" month-count="5">May</span>

<a href="#" class="future-months">&GT;</a>
```

You can also check it on JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/omerblink/4fzFD/6/

Thanks Guys :)

Omer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check your conditions first, Your array contains `0-12` which mean it's having `13` values in that there is one blank value too, so you have to check if your `num == 1` then you can again set `month-count` to `13-1 = 12` [Which bypasses that blank value in array]

Try this

```
$('.history-months').click(function () {
    var num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var future_month = parseFloat(num) == 1 ? (13 -1) : parseFloat(num) - 1; // Condition
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
});
```

Same way you can perform it for `next` navigation too! Just look at the code above and try for the next!

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fzFD/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Did it like this:

`$('.history-months').click(function () {
    var num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var future_month = parseFloat(num) - 1;
    if(future_month < 1) future_month = 12;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);
});
$('.future-months').click(function () {
    var num = $('.months').attr('month-count');
    var future_month = parseFloat(num) + 1; 
    if(future_month > 12) future_month = 1;
    $('.months').attr("month-count", future_month);
    $('.months').text($months[future_month]);`

http://jsfiddle.net/4fzFD/10/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys...

Dhaval your solution works like a charm but found a simple solution myself

I just change the:

```
if (num < 2)
```

TO

```
if (num < 3)
```

In .history-month